# RaspberryPi: snd_bcm2835 port to mainline kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi

i'm trying to port snd_bcm2835 to mainline kernel(mainly because the rpi official kernel doesn't use device tree).

now the vcio, vchiq, snd_bcm2835 can all be insmod into the kernel, but there's still no valid device for audio playback.
the module_init function of snd_bcm2835 module is bcm2835_alsa_device_init(), it's main job is(a simplify version):

```
 static int bcm2835_alsa_device_init(void)
 {
    platform_driver_register(&bcm2835_alsa0_driver);
    platform_driver_register(&bcm2835_alsa1_driver);
    //...repeat for 8 times
 }
```

this bcm2835_alsa_device_init function is called when i insmod snd_bcm2835, it can be run without error.

and the struct bcm2835_alsa0_driver, bcm2835_alsa1_driver look like:

```
 static struct platform_driver bcm2835_alsa0_driver = {
    .probe = snd_bcm2835_alsa_probe,
    .remove = snd_bcm2835_alsa_remove,
    //...
 }
```

the .probe function snd_bcm2835_alsa_probe is the main workhorse, but it was not been called.

so the question is when will this snd_bcm2835_alsa_probe been called?

Comment: Isn't is already in mainline? Check `sound/soc/bcm/bcm2835-i2s.c`. Update: ah, it seems you are working on PCM driver…

Answer (score 0):

I have ported 4.0 on raspberry pi using the following steps given by elinux, and i was succesfull . So you can also give a try:[Raspberry pi Upstream](http://elinux.org/RPi_Upstream_Kernel_Compilation)